# Locking Opportunity Splits

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-teams

We are looking to enable opportunity splits (enabled in [summer 13](https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_summer13_release_notes.pdf)).

Anyone using this along with some approval/lockdown mechanism?  Goal would be to prevent the changing of splits once agreed upon.  Has anyone successfully implemented this and mind sharing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update from Summer 14**

From the release notes on [Complete Customization Available for Opportunity Splits](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/rn_sales_opp_splits_fco.htm)

> You can customize opportunity splits in these ways:
>   - Set up validation rules
>   - Set up triggers

So you can now create a trigger that could use `addError()` onUpdate to prevent changes as required.

---

**Pre-Summer 14**

I was going to suggest creating a trigger on [OpportunitySplit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_opportunitysplit.htm) and using that to prevent changes via `addError()`. However, it appears you can't create triggers or validation rules for Opportuntiy Splits yet.

See [Opportunity split validation rule](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/Opportunity-split-validation-rule/td-p/636669) by [Rajit Joseph](https://success.salesforce.com/profile?u=00530000006drkWAAQ) (Product Manager for Sales Cloud at Salesforce)

> As of Summer '13, Opportunity Splits Object is not customizable i.e. it does not support addition of custom fields, validation rules, triggers, workflows etc on Opportunity Splits Object.  However, this is something we are planning in our roadmap #Safe Harbor.

This greatly reduces your options for locking down the splits.

The same post also contains as suggested work around:

> In the interim, customers can create a Visual Force (VF) Page with a similar look and feel to the standard Splits Multi-Edit UI page as in Summer '13 and enforce a client side validation on the VF Page.  Yes a small customization but would work in the interim, while we enhance the feature in our roadmap.  Recommended to have a similar look-and-feel for the custom VF page so that your end users have the same user experience for splitting opportunity and you dont need to re-train them when moving to standard UI (Splits Multi-Edit) with validation rules in future, when you have this capability natively in Salesforce.

Comment: Summer14 update: Complete Customization Available for Opportunity Splits
You can now customize opportunity splits to better serve your business needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a Custom Permission, Permission Set, and Validation Rule.

1. Create a Custom Permission called "Manage Opportunity Splits".
2. Create a Permission Set: "Manage Opportunity Splits".
3. Edit this Permission Set's "Custom Permissions".
4. Add custom permission "Manage Opportunity Splits".
5. On the Opportunity Split object, create a Validation Rule.

   - Rule Name: "Unauthorized"
   - Description: "Action performed on record was attempted by an unauthorized user."
   - Error Message: "You do not have permission to reduce Opportunity Splits."
   - Error Condition Formula:

```
$Permission.ManageOpportunitySplits = false &&
not(isnew()) &&
SplitOwner.Id != $User.Id &&
SplitPercentage < priorvalue(SplitPercentage)
```

*Note: Changing the Opportunity Amount will by necessity adjust the Opportunity Owner's split amount, so this formula specifically allows some split editing. It will prevent a user who lacks the appropriate permissions from **reducing** other people's splits.*

Assign the permission set to users as needed. You can also add the Custom Permission to profiles.

If you want to prevent Opportunity Splits from being deleted, you can create a Flow or trigger on "before delete" which should validate the same custom permission. For simplicity's sake, I did this by trying to change `IsDeleted` to "false" which is not allowed by the system. Pseudo-code for a Flow:

```
Object: Opportunity Split
Optimize for: Before the record is deleted

Decision element:
if {!$Permission.ManageOpportunitySplits} == false

Assignment element:
{!$Record.IsDeleted} = true  // throws an exception, thus preventing deletion
```